# Trying to fix a few problems in creating a game with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a game using Jquery however I do have 3 problems which I would appreciate help with.

First of all here are my codes.

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8"><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style20.css"><title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

    var spelLeftMax = $('#spelplan').width();
    var spelLeftMin = $('#box1').width();
    var spelTopMax = $('#spelplan').height();
    var spelTopMin = $('#box1').height();

    var x = $('#box1').position().left + $('#box1').width();
    var y = $('#box1').position().top + $('#box1').height();


    if (e.keyCode ==39){
        if (x < spelLeftMax) {
            $("#box1").animate({left: '+=20px'}, 0);
        }
    } 

    else if (e.keyCode ==37) {
        if (x > spelLeftMin) {
            $("#box1").animate({left: '-=20px'}, 0);
        }
    }

    else if (e.keycode ==40) {
        if (y < spelTopMax) {
            $("#box1").animate({top: '+=20px'}, 0)
        }
    }

    else if (e.keycode ==38) {
        if (y > spelTopMin) {
            $("#box1").animate({top: '-=20px'}, 0)
        }
    }

    else if (e.keyCode ==38) 
        $("#box1").animate({top: '-=20px'}, 0);
    else if (e.keyCode ==40) 
        $("#box1").animate({top: '+=20px'}, 0); 
    });

setInterval(spawnrand,1000);
});

function spawnrand(){
var spelplanWidth = $('#spelplan').width();
var randPosX = Math.floor((Math.random()*spelplanWidth));
var element = "<div class='rand'></div>"
$(element).css('left',randPosX);
$("#spelplan").append(element);
}


</script>
</head>
<body>
<header class="col-12 col-m-12">
<h1>Titel</h1>
</header>

<div id="rand_pos" class="rand"></div>
<div id="pos_log" class="log">x: 0<br />y: 0</div>
<button class="new_pos">New position</button>


<div id="spelplan">
<div id="box1"></div>
<br>
<p>Lives:</p>
<p>Score:</p>
</div>
</div>

</body>

</html>




        css:    `     

       *{
       box-sizing : border-box;
       margin:0;
       padding:0;
       }

body {
background-color: black;
}

header {
position:absolute;
top:50px;
color:white;
text-align:center;
}



#rand_pos{
position: absolute;
top:20%;
left: 30%;
z-index: 10;
}

#box1 {
background-color:red;
height:50px;
width:50px;
position:absolute;
left:30%;
top:150px;

}
p {
position:relative;
left:10px;
color:white;
}
#spelplan {
position:absolute;
left:25%;
top:20%;
height:600px;
width:600px;
background-color:blue;
border-style:double;
border-radius:40px;

}


.rand {
background-color:green;
height:15px;
width:15px;
position:relative;
left:30%;
top:150px;
z-index:-1;
}


.new_pos {
background: #ccc;
border: 1px solid #000;
padding: 5px;
box-shadow: 0 0 20px #555;
-webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in;
transition: all .2s ease-in;
}

.new_pos:hover {
background: #bbb;
box-shadow: 0 0 20px #222;
}


.new_pos:active {
box-shadow: 0 0 20px #000;
background: #aaa;
}


*:focus {
 outline: none;
}



.new_pos {
 position: fixed;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
cursor: pointer;
}








/* For mobile phones: */
[class*="col-"] {
width: 100%;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
/* For tablets: */
.col-m-1 {width: 8.33%;}
.col-m-2 {width: 16.66%;}
.col-m-3 {width: 25%;}
.col-m-4 {width: 33.33%;}
.col-m-5 {width: 41.66%;}
.col-m-6 {width: 50%;}
.col-m-7 {width: 58.33%;}
.col-m-8 {width: 66.66%;}
.col-m-9 {width: 75%;}
.col-m-10 {width: 83.33%;}
.col-m-11 {width: 91.66%;}
.col-m-12 {width: 100%;}
img {
    width: 80%;
    height: auto;
}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
/* For desktop: */
.col-1 {width: 8.33%;}
.col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
.col-3 {width: 25%;}
.col-4 {width: 33.33%;}
.col-5 {width: 41.66%;}
.col-6 {width: 50%;}
.col-7 {width: 58.33%;}
.col-8 {width: 66.66%;}
.col-9 {width: 75%;}
.col-10 {width: 83.33%;}
.col-11 {width: 91.66%;}
.col-12 {width: 100%;}
img {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
}`
```

Now my questions are:

1. How do I make the object you play as "#box1" unable to move out of the gameboard "spelplan"? I managed to make it unable to move out of it through the left and right side but it can still move out of the board through the top or bottom.
2. How do I make the food "rand" in my game spawn automatically and on a random location within the game board "spelplan"?
3. How do I make the object you play as "#box1" consume the green food "rand" in my game so that the food "rand" is removed when "#box1" moves ontop of it?

Comment: You'll likely get a better response if you ask one question per question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make an object appear automatically over and over again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43428176/how-to-make-an-object-appear-automatically-over-and-over-again)

Comment: @xar yes I used different questions and worded them better on that post after response from lee taylor