# How to make an object appear automatically over and over again

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a game using Jquery however I do have a few problems, this is a major one that I would really appreciate help with.

First of all here are my codes.

Html:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8"><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style20.css"><title>     Jquery spel</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).keydown(function(e){ 
    var spelLeftMax = $('#spelplan').width();
    var spelLeftMin = $('#box1').width();
    var spelTopMax = $('#spelplan').height();
    var spelTopMin = $('#box1').height();

    var x = $('#box1').position().left + $('#box1').width();
    var y = $('#box1').position().top + $('#box1').height();


    if (e.keyCode ==39){
        if (x < spelLeftMax) {
            $("#box1").animate({left: '+=20px'}, 0);
        }
    } 

    else if (e.keyCode ==37) {
        if (x > spelLeftMin) {
            $("#box1").animate({left: '-=20px'}, 0);
        }
    }

    else if (e.keycode ==40) {
        if (y < spelTopMax) {
            $("#box1").animate({top: '+=20px'}, 0)
        }
    }

    else if (e.keycode ==38) {
        if (y > spelTopMin) {
            $("#box1").animate({top: '-=20px'}, 0)
        }
    }

    else if (e.keyCode ==38) 
        $("#box1").animate({top: '-=20px'}, 0);
    else if (e.keyCode ==40) 
        $("#box1").animate({top: '+=20px'}, 0); 
    });

setInterval(spawnrand,1000);
});

function spawnrand(){
var spelplanWidth = $('#spelplan').width();
var randPosX = Math.floor((Math.random()*spelplanWidth));
var element = "<div class='rand'></div>"
$(element).css('left',randPosX);
$("#spelplan").append(element);
}


</script>
</head>
<body>
<header class="col-12 col-m-12">
<h1>Titel</h1>
</header>

<div id="rand_pos" class="rand"></div>
<div id="pos_log" class="log">x: 0<br />y: 0</div>
<button class="new_pos">New position</button>


<div id="spelplan">
<div id="box1"></div>
<br>
<p>Lives:</p>
<p>Score:</p>
</div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

css:

```
  *{
    box-sizing : border-box;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    }

body {
background-color: black;
}

header {
position:absolute;
top:50px;
color:white;
text-align:center;
}



#rand_pos{
position: absolute;
top:20%;
left: 30%;
z-index: 10;
}

#box1 {
background-color:red;
height:50px;
width:50px;
position:absolute;
left:30%;
top:150px;

}
p {
position:relative;
left:10px;
color:white;
}
#spelplan {
position:absolute;
left:25%;
top:20%;
height:600px;
width:600px;
background-color:blue;
border-style:double;
border-radius:40px;

}


.rand {
background-color:green;
height:15px;
width:15px;
position:relative;
left:30%;
top:150px;
z-index:-1;
}


.new_pos {
background: #ccc;
border: 1px solid #000;
padding: 5px;
box-shadow: 0 0 20px #555;
-webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in;
transition: all .2s ease-in;
}

.new_pos:hover {
background: #bbb;
box-shadow: 0 0 20px #222;
}


.new_pos:active {
box-shadow: 0 0 20px #000;
background: #aaa;
}


*:focus {
 outline: none;
}



.new_pos {
 position: fixed;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
cursor: pointer;
}








/* For mobile phones: */
[class*="col-"] {
width: 100%;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
/* For tablets: */
.col-m-1 {width: 8.33%;}
.col-m-2 {width: 16.66%;}
.col-m-3 {width: 25%;}
.col-m-4 {width: 33.33%;}
.col-m-5 {width: 41.66%;}
.col-m-6 {width: 50%;}
.col-m-7 {width: 58.33%;}
.col-m-8 {width: 66.66%;}
.col-m-9 {width: 75%;}
.col-m-10 {width: 83.33%;}
.col-m-11 {width: 91.66%;}
.col-m-12 {width: 100%;}
img {
    width: 80%;
    height: auto;
}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
/* For desktop: */
.col-1 {width: 8.33%;}
.col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
.col-3 {width: 25%;}
.col-4 {width: 33.33%;}
.col-5 {width: 41.66%;}
.col-6 {width: 50%;}
.col-7 {width: 58.33%;}
.col-8 {width: 66.66%;}
.col-9 {width: 75%;}
.col-10 {width: 83.33%;}
.col-11 {width: 91.66%;}
.col-12 {width: 100%;}
img {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
}`
```

Now my questions:

1. How do I make the food "rand" in my game spawn automatically?
2. How do I make the automatically spawning food "rand"  spawn on a random location within the gameboard "spelplan"?

Once again I would really appreciate any help I can get, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

This isnt really working:

```
var element = "<div class='rand'></div>"
$(element).css('left',randPosX);
$("#spelplan").append(element);
```

cause element is just a string. May do this:

```
var element = $("<div class='rand'></div>").css('left',randPosX);
$("#spelplan").append(element);
```

Comment: @Jonasw Thank you so much it now spawns automatically! Now the issue is that I need the objects "rand" to spawn within the gameboard "spelplan" any suggestions on how I do that?

Comment: @guest271314 you should append the jquery object not the string `element`

Comment: @John doesnt it? trough the left:random()?

Comment: @Jonasw The objects "rand" spawn correctly corresponding to the width of the gameboard "spelplan" but the height is wrong which makes some of the objects appear below or above the gameboard instead of within. EDIT: When I think about it this is connected to a different problem I have which is to keep the object you play as "#box1" unable to move out of the gameboard. I managed to make it unable to move out of the gameboard to the left or right but it can still move out of it through the top and bottom of the gameboard.

Comment: @John all in all a game is not the right place to start with JS. The proper solution would be a canvas, and a game library....